# How targets should look like for UNet

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have implemented UNet from scratch for medical image segmentation. Everything was working fine for testing data, where targets for 6 classes where saved on 6 channels, so mask shape was `(H,W,6)` and `target.min(), target.max(): 0.0, 1.0`

For loss function I was using `torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()`, and at the end I was using sigmoid to get the output:

```
pred = torch.sigmoid(pred)
pred = pred.data.cpu().numpy()
```

Now I jumped to different data available on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/prostate-cancer-grade-assessment). The label masks are stored in an RGB format and the label information is stored in the red (R) channel. So it's basically `(H,W)` with 6 classes (0 is the background):

```
np.unique(target): [0 1 2 3 5]
np.unique(target1): [0 1 2]
np.unuque(target2): [0 1 4]
etc.
```

How do I proceed? I could probably create one hot encoding for `target`, but it would be 6 additional channels for images around 1024x1024. Is there maybe different way, maybe another loss function?

Comment: You need to use `CrossEntropyLoss` function and that doesn't require a one-hot encoding for the target. You can read it's [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) for more details and usage information.

Answer (score 0):

The loss you are using —`BCEWithLogitsLoss`— stands for Binary Cross Entropy while `WithLogits` suggests that is should be used with one-hot vectors. As stated in the documentation it is simply a `BCELoss` preceded by a sigmoid implemented in a numerically stable way.

In both cases the loss is designed for **binary classification**, so the inputs should be floats in [0, 1]. This means that when using `BCELoss` alone, you should apply a sigmoid of a softmax before applying the loss.

As stated in a comment if your targets are not one-hot encoded and the labels are stored as indices you should use `CrossEntropyLoss` which is specifically designed for this use case according to the documentation. This loss is a combination of a `LogSoftmax` and `NLLLoss` which means that it works for multi-class classification problems and that the output tensor should have a trailing dimension of C where C is the number of classes.